# multiple levels of pivot_table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do multiple rounds of pivot_table to turn my flat data into something I can use for a project.

Here is some sample data organized similarly to how it's coming out of the database.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[123456, 'Student A', 'Algebra I', 9, 'S1', 'A'],
    [123456, 'Student A', 'Algebra I', 9, 'S2', 'B'],
    [123456, 'Student A', 'Geometry', 10, 'S1', 'B'],
    [987654, 'Student B', 'Algebra I', 9, 'S1', 'C'],
    [987654, 'Student B', 'Geometry', 9, 'S1', 'B']],
    columns=('student_number', 'student_name', 'course_name', 'grade_level', 'storecode', 'grade')
)
```

```
|    |   student_number | student_name   | course_name   |   grade_level | storecode   | grade   |
|---:|-----------------:|:---------------|:--------------|--------------:|:------------|:--------|
|  0 |           123456 | Student A      | Algebra I     |             9 | S1          | A       |
|  1 |           123456 | Student A      | Algebra I     |             9 | S2          | B       |
|  2 |           123456 | Student A      | Geometry      |            10 | S1          | B       |
|  3 |           987654 | Student B      | Algebra I     |             9 | S1          | C       |
|  4 |           987654 | Student B      | Geometry      |             9 | S1          | B       |
```

Ultimately, we want the output to look something like this.  Students can take multiple math classes in a year, and I would like to see each listed in its own set of columns.

```
                                  | 9           |    |    | 9           |    |    | 10          |    |    | 10          |    |    |
                                  | 1           |    |    | 2           |    |    | 1           |    |    | 2           |    |    |
                                  | course_name | S1 | S2 | course_name | S1 | S2 | course_name | S1 | S2 | course_name | S1 | S2 |
|-----------------|---------------|-------------|----|------------------|----|----|-------------|----|----|-------------|----|----|
| student_number  | student_name  |             |    |    |             |    |    |             |    |    |             |    |    |
| 123456          | Student A     | Algebra 1   | A  | B  |             |    |    | Geometry    | B  |    |             |    |    |
| 987654          | Student B     | Algebra 1   | C  |    | Geometry    | B  |    |             |    |    |             |    |    |
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Produce a unique rank per course per student per grade_level
df['R'] = df.groupby(['student_number', 'grade_level'])['course_name'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense')).astype(int)
```

```
|    |   student_number | student_name   | course_name   |   grade_level | storecode   | grade   |   R |
|---:|-----------------:|:---------------|:--------------|--------------:|:------------|:--------|----:|
|  0 |           123456 | Student A      | Algebra I     |             9 | S1          | A       |   1 |
|  1 |           123456 | Student A      | Algebra I     |             9 | S2          | B       |   1 |
|  2 |           123456 | Student A      | Geometry      |            10 | S1          | B       |   1 |
|  3 |           987654 | Student B      | Algebra I     |             9 | S1          | C       |   1 |
|  4 |           987654 | Student B      | Geometry      |             9 | S1          | B       |   2 |
```

Here is where I perform my first pivot, and I like the shape of the result.

```
# Pivot by storecode
df = df.pivot_table(index=['student_number', 'student_name', 'course_name', 'grade_level', 'R'], columns='storecode', aggfunc=max).fillna("")

# Flatten the columns
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

# Reset the index
df = df.reset_index()
```

```
|    |   student_number | student_name   | course_name   |   grade_level |   R | S1   | S2   |
|---:|-----------------:|:---------------|:--------------|--------------:|----:|:-----|:-----|
|  0 |           123456 | Student A      | Algebra I     |             9 |   1 | A    | B    |
|  1 |           123456 | Student A      | Geometry      |            10 |   1 | B    |      |
|  2 |           987654 | Student B      | Algebra I     |             9 |   1 | C    |      |
|  3 |           987654 | Student B      | Geometry      |             9 |   2 | B    |      |
```

This is the closest I've been able to get at my next step.  It looks like I need to move the levels around and possible sort the columns

```
df.pivot_table(index=['student_number', 'student_name'], columns=['grade_level', 'R'], aggfunc=max).fillna("")
```

```
|               | storecode   | S1 |    |    | S2 |    |    | course_name |            |            |
|               | grade_level | 9  |    | 10 | 9  |    | 10 | 9           |            | 10         |
|               | R           | 1  | 2  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 1  | 1           | 2          | 1          |
|:--------------|:------------|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:------------|:-----------|:-----------|
| student_number| student_name|    |    |    |    |    |    |             |            |            |
| 123456        | Student A   | A  |    | B  | B  |    |    | Algebra I   |            | Geometry   |
| 987654        | Student B   | C  | B  |    |    |    |    | Algebra I   | Geometry   |            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the indices based on `level`. Level 0 in this case is slightly tricky. So, I projected it before sorting the indices; `[['course_name', 'S1', 'S2']]`

```
(df
 .pivot_table(index=['student_number', 'student_name'], columns=['grade_level', 'R'], aggfunc=max)
 .fillna("")
 [['course_name', 'S1', 'S2']]
 .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2], sort_remaining=False)
)
```

[image]

Also, you don't need any aggregate function, so you can directly go for [pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
(df
 .pivot(index=['student_number', 'student_name'], columns=['grade_level', 'R'])
 .fillna("")
 [['course_name', 'S1', 'S2']]
 .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2], sort_remaining=False)
)
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic.  The only thing I added was a re-order of the levels to have them stack the way I wanted:

`.reorder_levels( [1,2,0], axis=1 )`

Thanks for the tip on `.pivot()` too.  I tried it before and got an error somewhere, but it must have been something else I had wrong.

Thank you so much!